# hide data of the datasets in radar chart?

Tags: chart.js

I'm doing a radar chart but am having some problems. I have read the docs but it doesn't work. I want to hide the data of the datasets but I don't know how to do it? This is the picture. I want to hide data 20, 25, 30 as you see [image]

and I also know how to spacing the two legends like justify-content between

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `hidden` if you set this to true in your dataset the data wont be shown until someone clicks the legend or you do it programatically.

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.2/chart.js" integrity="sha512-n8DscwKN6+Yjr7rI6mL+m9nS4uCEgIrKRFcP0EOkIvzOLUyQgOjWK15hRfoCJQZe0s6XrARyXjpvGFo1w9N3xg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: this is not what I mean. I want to hide the data 7 8 9 10 11, not the dataset